# Date version of

Tags: abbreviations, range-inclusion, shorthand

When referring to part of a book starting from one page but without a final page, it's common to see this referred to as (*e*.*g*.) "pg. 55 *ff*", as described [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ff.).

**Is there something similar for a year reference?**

For instance, one might say, "I worked at ACME Corp (2011ff)". Of course, it might be best in some circumstances to write out something like (2011–*present*), but that defeats the point of this question.

Comment: Hello, jvriesem. Dictionaries nowadays carry definitions for abbreviations. Have you looked in any to check for the extended usage you query?

Comment: I've just checked in 7; 6 give the definition, but restricted to 'and the following **pages**' (with one broadening to  '... ,paragraphs etc') and one to '... ,line, etc'. I'd say '1654ff' has to apply to pages in a (big) book, lines, paragraphs (where these are numbered). Ellipses are in general use.

Comment: Your *-present* is the most common. For lifespans for living persons, it's usually given as an unadorned hyphen, e.g. *Barack Obama (1961-)*.  In prose contexts, it's often given as *1961 onwards*. Etc.  There is no special abbreviation that I am aware of.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I have not checked any dictionaries. (Usually I search a dictionary if I want more information about a known word or construct; not if I'm looking for something unknown.) I searched online a bit, but no luck! :-)

Comment: A search for a general answer would be difficult, but a check on the possible extended usage  "I worked at ACME Corp (2011ff)" you suggest is reasonable. After all, 'ff' might be derived from 'and following' (which it isn't). And indeed, outside the literary domain It doesn't seem to be an actual usage.